# SpringBoot accessing params inside method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

New to Spring/SpringBoot, I have two methods like bellow -

1.

```
@GetMapping("/score")
public UserScoreRes getUserScore(@RequestHeader("api-key") String apiKey,
                                @RequestHeader("jwt") String jwt,
                                @RequestParam(name = "date", defaultValue = "2022-07-15") String dateStr) {

.....
}
```

2. 

```
@GetMapping(value = "/score", params ="behaviour-version=2")
public UserScoreResV2 getUserScoreV2(@RequestHeader("api-key") String apiKey,
                                    @RequestHeader("jwt") String jwt,
                                    @RequestParam(name = "date", defaultValue = "2022-07-15") String dateStr) {

....
}
```

In method 2 (`getUserScoreV2`), **how can I get** `behaviour-version` **inside the method?**

Tried with -

```
@GetMapping(value = "/score", params ="behaviour-version=2")
public UserScoreResV2 getUserScoreV2(@RequestHeader("api-key") String apiKey,
                                    @RequestHeader("jwt") String jwt,
                                    @RequestParam(name = "behaviour-version", required = false) String behaviourVersion,
                                    @RequestParam(name = "date", defaultValue = "2022-07-15") String dateStr) {

....
}
```

but, it is **not** working.

Can not modify method 1 (`getUserScore`) because a version is released in production with that.

Comment: Do you want same endpoint but different implementation am I right?

Comment: do you want to handle this in controller level?

Comment: Why would you need it? The value is always 2... The arguments in `@GetMapping` (or `@RequestMapping` for that matter) are, as the name implies, used for **mapping**. So if you have a request with the parameter `behaviour-version=3` it won't match and not invoke this method. So getting that parameter as an argument doesn't add much as in this case it will always be 2.

Comment: @YJR - You are correct, I want to have "same endpoint but different implementation". How to do it? Can please mention different ways to do it?

Comment: @M. Deinum - You are correct, If I wish this value "behaviour-version" to be dynamic, as input from the user, then how to do it?

Comment: Add it as another `@RequestParam` and remove the `=2` from the mapping information. Now if the parameter is present it will call the second method, else the first.

Comment: @M. Deinum - it will give "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping."

Comment: Then you haven't done as I said you should... Your `@GetMapping` should read `@GetMapping(value = "/score", params ="behaviour-version")` that way Spring can determine which to invoke.

Comment: What you want to do can do using handler interceptor. Added that as answer. Check whether it work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@GetMapping(value = "/score", params ="behaviour-version=2")
public UserScoreResV2 getUserScoreV2(@RequestHeader("api-key") String apiKey,
                             @RequestHeader("jwt") String jwt,
                             @RequestParam(name = "date", defaultValue = "2022-07-15") String dateStr,
                             ServletRequest request) {
    String behaviorVersion = request.getParameter("behaviour-version");
}
```

### warning

As Deinum mentioned, behavior-version should be 2.
Otherwise, you can't send request. The server will return 400 error

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using handler interceptor. What you have to do is when application recieve a request for `/score` endpoint with `behaviour_version` header or param you have to redirect that to the another endpoint through preHandler (ex: `/score/v2` ).

Then caller can send request for same endpoint with additional header/param. Redirecting according to header do by springboot interceptor.

Ex handler inteceptor:

```
public class ScoreInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
        public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    
         if(request.getParameter(behaviour_v)=="2"){
         response.redirect('/score/v1');
         return false;
    }
         return true;
    }
}
```